# Android Studio || GDK 'hello word' || import com.google.android.glass.app.Card || Cannot Resolve Symbol 'google'

Tags: android, android-studio, google-glass

What I am trying to do with my google glass is pretty simple: create/display a hello world card for google glass

issue is::

when i add this:

```
import com.google.android.glass.app.Card
```

I get This:

```
Cannot Resolve Symbol 'google'
```

I did [this](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/quick-start):

Minimum and Target SDK Versions: 15 (There is only one Glass version, so minimum and target SDK are the same.)
Compile with: Glass Development Kit Sneak Peek

and i made a change to the gradel.build[compile sdk version...it was 15/changed to what is below]

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Sneak Peek:15"
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 15
    }
}
```

I feel like I'm missing something simple/a set up issue/not sure what it is.

got any suggestions?

Comment: Just to rule out other issues, do the sample projects import OK?  They don't use gradle.  Also what version of Android Studio?

Answer (score 12):

It looks like you have things set up correctly, but Android Studio is still under development, and can still be a bit glitchy when it comes to libraries and add-ons. Here are some troubleshooting steps that may help:

- Re-import your project
- Under module settings -> Project -> Project SDK -> Edit..., make sure that the Build Target is "Glass Development Kit Sneak Peek"
- And if all else fails, you can add gdk.jar, found in `sdk/add-ons/addon-google_gdk-google-15/libs`, to your classpath by adding it as an external library.

Comment: Changing the Build Target to "Glass Development Kit Sneak Peek" fixed it for me. However, I must have a different version of Android Studio because I could not find the same options as described in the answer. Instead, I had to do this: File -> Other Settings -> Default Project Structure... -> SDKs (under Platform Settings) -> Android API 15 Platform -> Build target: Glass Development Kit Sneak Peek (4.0.3).

Comment: But now I just get the same error when I try to build the project... it just doesn't show up in red before then. -_- I can't figure out how to get this thing to compile, it keeps saying "Gradle: error: package com.google.android.glass.timeline does not exist"

Answer (score 5):

The top answer is a bit old.  Since the GDK is no longer a sneak peek, use:

```
compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19"
```

Make sure you've downloaded the Glass Development Kit Preview from Tools > SDK Manager, and that you're running the latest version of Android Studio (0.55 and up.)

Comment: After all this, when I try to build the APK, I still get a message "Error: Default Activity not found".

Comment: @Arun: That's fine!  Just choose "Don't start activity".  You should be able to install the app and launch via a voice trigger.

Answer (score -2):

Why don´t you use a sample to start your project?
New Project -> Other -> Android Sample Project
You can use the StopWatch to make that.

If you don´t want, be sure that your manifest has

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

Check if the GDK Sneak Peek is installed.

This message

```
Cannot Resolve Symbol 'google'
```

Look like a syntax error or a include error in your eclipse.

Check is the Glass Development Kit Sneak Peep is include as our library.
Right Click your project -> Properties -> Java Build path -> Libraries
Check too is your Project Build Target is correct on Android option.

Comment: What your describing is Eclipse. The question was for Android Studio, which Jenny & Tony pointed out is still very beta and doesn't have any glass template projects like Eclipse does that I'm aware of. 

I just tried your recommendation in Eclipse though and got an apk onto Glass for the first time so Cheers to that! 
USE ECLIPSE.