# Package com.google.android.glass.media does not exist

Tags: android, google-gdk

I'm trying to generate APK via Build > Build Bundle(s) / APK(s) > Build APK(s)

Getting build failed with following Errors:

```
error: package com.google.android.glass.media does not exist        
error: package com.google.android.glass.widget does not exist       
error: cannot find symbol class CardScrollView      
error: cannot find symbol class CardScrollAdapter       
error: cannot find symbol variable Sounds
error: cannot find symbol class CardBuilder    
error: package CardBuilder does not exist
```

As far as I understand that belongs to GDK (Glass Development Kit) Preview, which I already can see in module level build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19"
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        .......
}
```

One more thing, Event Log says:

```
Unable to detect adb version, exit value: 0xc0000005
```

Android Studio: 3.5.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20695542/android-studio-gdk-hello-word-import-com-google-android-glass-app-card

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman no that's not... read question and answer provided there you shared above

Comment: Before trying to generate the apk did you try to do a `clean` project?